# Why doesn´t the childNodes work in my JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, html, children, child-nodes

I just started programming and I wanted to test some of the basic things in JS. I wanted to try using childNodes (saw it in a tutorial). Does anyone know why it doesn't work?

```js
function here() {
  var x = document.body;
  var y = x.childNodes;
}
window.alert(y[1].innerHTML);
```

```html
<html>
<h1 onclick="here()">
  click here!
</h1>

<body>
  <p>
    Just some text!
  </p>

  <p>
    Another text!
  </p>
</body>

</html>
```

I searched for a mistake or a typing error but I couldn't find one.

Comment: You declare your variables inside a function, and then try to reference one outside the function. Put the `window.alert()` call *inside* the handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few problems:

1. You're calling `window.alert(y[1].innerHTML);` outside of your `here()` function. `y` is defined inside of `here()`, so you can't access `y` outside of `here()`. This is a simple fix: just move the `alert()` call into your function.
2. Your HTML is practically nonsensical. An `<h1>` element should not be outside of `<body>`

I've fixed these probelms below:

```js
function here() {
  var x = document.body;
  var y = x.childNodes;
  alert(y[1].innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <h1 onclick="here()">
    click here!
  </h1>
  <p>
    Just some text!
  </p>

  <p>
    Another text!
  </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, you don't need to call `window.alert()` because `window.` is implied. This isn't necessarily a problem though.